# How to set a global soap ui basic authentication and the Accept as application/json

Tags: rest, soapui

How can i set a global soap ui basic authentication and the Accept as application/json so i do not have to enter it manually for every request

Comment: hello, are you using Soap UI or ReadyAPI (Soap UI pro) ?

Answer (score 1):

to set a header to every requests: use the following groovy script (adapt to your needs)

```
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.testSuiteList.each
{
    suite ->
    name = suite.getName()

    suite.testCaseList.each{
        TC -> 
        // parse each Test Case
        TC.testStepList.each{
            TS ->
            // parse each Test Step
            if (TS.config.type == "restrequest")
            {
                // only on REST request type steps
                // check its headers
                headers = TS.getHttpRequest().getRequestHeaders()
                //log.info "headers = " + headers
                refHeaderName = "Accept" // search Accept header
                found = false
                headers.find(){
                    hd ->
                    //log.info "header name = ${hd.key}, value = ${hd.value}"

                    if(hd.key == refHeaderName)
                    {
                        found = true
                    }
                }

                if (found == false)
                {
                    log.info "testSuite $name - testCase ${TC.getName()} - testStep ${TS.getName()}"
                    // the header does not exists, create it
                    headers.put("Accept", "application/json")
                    //log.info "add a new header : " + headers
                    TS.testRequest.setRequestHeaders(headers)
                }
            }
        } // TS each
    } // TC 
} // TSuite each
```

This will set the Accept application/json header in each request that does not have it

Concerning authentication, it depends if you're using SOAP UI in the PRO version (Ready API) or not 
If you use Ready API, you have to create an Environment (in the tab 'SoapUI Pro'), with appropriate endpoint, etc.

Then in the 'Projects' tab select your project resources (blue arrows), it will enable the 'Auth Manager' services, select them

In the Auth Repository tab, create your profile with type 'Basic' for basic authentication, set your Username and Password (I don't know what Domain is used for) and Pre-emptive auth as 'Authenticate pre-emptively'

In the Auth manager tab, select your project then your newly created profile and say Yes to the prompt 'apply selected profile to all children items' so it can apply your credentials to all the requests in your project.

good luck

Alexandre